# Problems moving free space between two partitions

Tags: mac, partition, disk-space, disk-volume

On my Mac I installed another version on Mac OS (10.11) on a new partition, with just the minimum required space available.

Now I would like to move and add some free space to it, having some problems in running the OS smoothly.
I tried with IPartiton/Stellar Partition Manager and the latter said the process was completed succesfully, but actually it left me just unallocated space, which does not belong neither to Partition A nor to partition B.

Now the situation is as follows:

```
Air-di-Edoardo:~ edoardo$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            88.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 2          31.6 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk0s5

    Air-di-Edoardo:~ edoardo$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  171829272      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  172238912    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  173508448   61675864      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  235184312    1269536      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236453848     524295         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

As you can see, having installed two OS, I also have two recovery partitions (can I delete one of them maybe?)

I am not sure how to move that unallocated space to "Macintosh HD2".

I tried in recovery mode with:

```
diskutil resizevoume /dev/disk0s4 R
```

but the resizing process aborted with error: "the requested change in size is too small" (though volume Macintosh HD2 appears to be ok)

With a command like

```
sudo gpt add -b 236453848 -i 6 -s 524288 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

I could assign the unallocateed space to a new partition but this would not solve my problem..

Could you please suggest me anything?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What OS, precisely? iPartition is abandonware, can't handle CoreStorage or APFS. I'd recommend [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) as its replacement.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you don't use APFS and use a single APFS Container with two partitions. Heck, I do that and triple boot macOS versions.  Partitions within a container share the free space.  Unless you are running an OS less than High Sierra...

Comment: Hi thank you for your answers. Actually i tried both with IPartition and Stellar Partition Manager. The first one failed in creating a bootable image on several USB pendrives (don't know why), while the latter delivered the error which I described.With regards to OS, yes I run Mac OS 10.7 Lion and 10.11 El Cpatain, so I cannot use APFS container..

Comment: I've had no issues using [GParted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to move mac partitions.  You could try it to move partition 5 to the end so the free space is between partitions 4 and 5.  Alternatively just delete partition 5 as there is no point having 2 recovery partitions (you can back it up first if you want).  Then you'll be able to extend partition 4 which is what you are wanting to do if I understand correctly.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your suggestion. Yes, i deleted the recovery partition (disk0s5) and then with the command resizevolume R I managed to shrink the blank unallocated space.